# Can not save webrtc video div as image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to save div to image using canvas.toBlob it its producing empty white picture. I want to take a screenshot from a webrtc video maybe, how can I do it with canvas method ? Or is there any other way of doing it in javascript ?
My code is below

```
   canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
             });
```

Comment: Are any errors logged at `console`? Is `saveAs` defined?

Comment: We need more information to help you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried this guide I found after a quick google search? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos

Comment: I don't have access to inner webrtc JSL library. I only have local and remote video containers and I send them to library as arguments. I am not dealing with webRTC mechanism.

Comment: @guest271314 There is no error because I get image but it is all white, I think it is because that library written for static divs not dynamic videos streams.

Comment: Show us how you are drawing your video on the canvas in the context of this saving 3 lines of code.

Comment: html2canvas(document.getElementById('local-
   container')).then(canvas => {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
                    });
                });

Comment: I have local and remote video container divs in my html file, thats it I do not control webRTC mechanism, using an JSL library for that.And I run this code when there is video in the containers and I get no result but an empty image with exactly same size of my container.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the commands, the code from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) should work for you.

Assuming your library is not dealing directly with the webRTC code, but the canvas already contains the WebRTC streams, you could try the code from the MDN example:

```
function takepicture() {
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
if (width && height) {
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  photo.setAttribute('src', data);
} else {
  clearphoto();
}
```

}

Hope it helps!